# Elasticsearch number of results for each filter

Tags: elasticsearch, search, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-6

consider I have a data set and multiple filters,
when user add new filters or remove new filters, I want to know, how many records resist under each filter.

for example I want to show the results like this :

tag1 ( 100 )

tag2 ( 130 )

city1 ( 77 )

city2 ( 95 )

how can I achieve this using Elasticsearch 6 ?

look consider , user has selected city A as a filter now he sees search result filtered by city,

now other filters are for example category and genre,
I want to show number of records if I choose category B as well, or if I choose category C,in front of category itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use following for filter with bool query, and agg for item count per tag.

Sample of document:

```
{
    "id": 8,
    "title": "eight",
    "tags": [
        {"name":"tag1"}, 
        {"name":"tag2"}
    ]
}
```

Query:

```
{
  "size":0,
  "query" : {
      "bool" : {
          "must" : [
            { "term" : { "tags.name" : "tag2" } },
            { "term" : { "tags.name" : "tag3" } }
          ]
        }
    },
  "aggs": {
    "tags": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "tags.name"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated question, I need to know number of records if user select any of filters , in front of that filter

Comment: this query return whats you want